# expo-sqlite как добавить колонку в таблицу, если колонка еще не существует?

Tags: sqlite, react-native, expo

Использую expo-sqlite. Хочу добавить к уже существующей таблице колонку, если она не существует через  `IF NOT EXISTS` это не работает.
**В интернете нашел что нужно объединить вот эти 2 кода:**

```
ALTER TABLE table_name ADD COLUMN column_name TEXT
```

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS CNTREC FROM pragma_table_info('table_name') WHERE name='column_name'
```

пробовал через

`IFF`, `CASE THEN ELSE END`,

такой вариант тоже пробовал

```
IF NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT
    *
  FROM
    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
  WHERE
    TABLE_NAME = 'table_name' AND COLUMN_NAME = 'column_name')
BEGIN
  ALTER TABLE table_name
    ADD column_name TEXT NULL
  END;
```

Но ничего из этого не работает, подскажите пожалуйста еще какие нибудь варианты.

Comment: Да нафига? просто добавляй. Если поле уже существует, добавление приведёт к ошибке, которую ты обработаешь на клиенте, и всё.

Comment: Разве не будет добавляться много колонок с одинаковым названием?

Comment: В структуре таблицы в принципе не может существовать два одноимённых поля (если есть - структура разрушена).

Comment: Благодарю, за ответ

Answer (score 0):

Мне пришла мысль как это можно сделать через  JS, если кому пригодится. доделайте это под себя:

```
export class DB {
    static AlterColumn(){
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            db.transaction(tx => {
                tx.executeSql( `ALTER TABLE table_name ADD COLUMN column_name DATE NOT NULL DEFAULT ''`,
                    [],
                    resolve,
                    (_, error) => reject(error)
                );
            });
        });
    }
}
```

далее в js файле

```
...
  const arr = useSelector(state => state.db_name.table_name);

  const filterArr = arr.filter(table_name =>  table_name.column_name === '' );
  if(filterArr.length === 0){
     DB.AlterColumn();
  }
...
```